# Calculo em php dando erro

Tags: php, matemática

No meu site tenho o seguinte código para calcular descontos:

```
$valor_a_ser_calculado =$_POST['loc']; // valor original
$quantos_porcento = 75/100; //isso equivale a 7% 
$loc = $quantos_porcento * $valor_a_ser_calculado . "\n";
```

só que está dando o seguinte erro:

```
PHP Warning:  A non-numeric value encountered in /home/jp/public_html/orcamento.php on line 6
```

Gostaria de saber como resolver isso

Comment: `$loc = ($quantos_porcento * $valor_a_ser_calculado ). "\n";`

Comment: Separe a parte numérica da parte string com parenteses. Além disso, verifique se o valor do POST está correto antes de mais nada.

Comment: Coloquei os parentes e deu erro, e sim o valor do post está correto.

Comment: A onde eu tenho que colocar os parentes exatamente?

Answer (score 2):

Você tem dois problemas imediatos no código: Não está verificando se o valor do POST está correto, e misturando multiplicação com concatenação. Teste com isto:

```
$valorasercalculado = $_POST['loc']; // valor original
echo "Valor original: $valorasercalculado <br>";

$quantos_porcento = 75/100; //isso equivale a 7.5% 
echo "Porcentagem: $quantosporcento <br>";

$loc = $quantos_porcento * $valor_a_ser_calculado;
echo "Resultado: $loc <br>";
```

Neste caso, somente terá *warnings* se algum dos valores não for numérico.

O ideal seria repensar algo nesse sentido:

```
$valorasercalculado = isset($_POST['loc']) ? $_POST['loc'] : 0;
```

Ou mesmo

```
if (!isset($_POST['loc'])) die 'Valor não fornecido';
```

logo no começo do código.

Como bem lembrado pelo colega @RafaelSalomao, o PHP tem uma função específica para testar se um valor é numérico. Juntando as duas idéias:

```
if (!isset($_POST['loc'])) die 'Valor não fornecido';
if (!is_numeric($_POST['loc'])) die 'O valor precisa ser numérico';
```

(lembrando que o ! antes da função significa "not", nos casos acima, se o valor NÃO for setado, o script para. Se o valor NÃO for numérico, o script também para).

Manual:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-numeric.php

Comment: Bacco o mérito da resposta é seu! Apenas sugeri uma edição utilizando a função is_numeric do php para validar o valor enviado por POST. Lembrando que deverá também validar essa condição em seu formulário.

Comment: Bacco muito obrigado funcionou perfeitamente, valeu aí.

Comment: @RafaelSalomão agradeço a intenção, fique à vontade para propor uma resposta alternativa (múltiplas respostas são bem-vindas no site, desde que complementares). Inicialmente minha intenção foi apenas fazer com que o autor verifique os parâmetros.

Comment: @JoãoPedroAlmeida vou melhorar um pouco a resposta, vale notar que o colega Rafael Salomão sugeriu o uso de is_numeric para que você veja se o valor passado é realmente um número.

Comment: @RafaelSalomão acrescentei sua sugestão de uma outra forma, grato.

Comment: Ok, Irmão, ficou luxo!

Comment: @RafaelSalomão mas se quiser complementar com outra resposta, é bem-vindo!

Comment: @RafaelSalomão valeu cara, as duas respostas foram boas porém a do bacco deu mais certo para o meu caso.